# Visiting a filter page should ensure you are logged in

Tags: bug, status-completed

If I'm not logged in, when I navigate to my ["favorite tags" filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/favorite-tags) via bookmark I get a "Page not found" error page and no indication of the actual problem (I'm not logged in).

Visiting *any* account-dependent page like filters or settings should first ensure that you are logged in, and ask you to log in if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this link was only exposed before you clicked the "Favorite Tags" link for the very first time (thus initializing your Favorite Tags filter), and then never again.

Nevertheless, it links to the login page for anonymous users now.